# ImageProcessingModule.ValidatingRequest not found

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, imageprocessor

I'm trying to follow this guiode https://kieron.codes/blog/using-webp-images-in-umbraco/ to make my ubraco(V7) display all images as webp.

My problem is in this code - where i get the error "ImageProcessingModule' does not contain a definition for 'ValidatingRequest'"

```
public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    ImageProcessingModule.ValidatingRequest += ImageProcessingModule_ValidatingRequest;
}
```

I have tried to reinstall the nuget package to both ImageProcessor.Plugins.WebP and ImageProcessor.Web - but the problem remains.

Any input to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the namespace on your file?

```
using ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules;
```

Comment: Yes it is included